# Rotating raycast2D back and forth with object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, 2d, game-physics

I made a circle and attach a lazer box on top of it.

[image]

The lazer will fire a raycast to its upper y axis (straight up). I also add a line renderer to view it.

[image]

I want the raycast to rotate 90 degrees back and forth. Sort of like its scanning everything on top. My problem is that its not working properly. It does rotate back and forth but If I move the x position of the lazer object, the raycast will rotate in a weird angle.

**Script for lazer object**

```
public LineRenderer lineRenderer;
public LayerMask layerMask;
public float laserSpeed;

Vector3 pointA;
Vector3 pointB;
Vector3 castPosition;
RaycastHit2D rayCast;

float time;

void Start()
{
    pointA = transform.eulerAngles + new Vector3(0f, 0f, 90f);

    pointB = transform.eulerAngles + new Vector3(0f, 0f, -90f);
}

void Update()
{
    time = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * laserSpeed, 1);
    transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(pointA, pointB, time);
    castPosition = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    rayCast = Physics2D.Raycast(castPosition, transform.TransformDirection(Vector2.up), 10f, layerMask);

    lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, castPosition);
    lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, transform.TransformDirection(Vector2.up) * 10f);
        
}
```

Comment: @derHugo well, I just started unity, so I took tiny pieces of code and mix it together. Can u show the proper way of doing it ?

Answer (score 2):

- Using [`eulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html) for continuous animations is quite "dangerous". Unity stores the rotations as [`Quaternion`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) and there are multiple ways of how to represent these in euler space!

  > When you read the `.eulerAngles` property, Unity converts the `Quaternion`'s internal representation of the rotation to Euler angles. Because, there is more than one way to represent any given rotation using Euler angles, the values you read back out may be quite different from the values you assigned. This can cause confusion if you are trying to gradually increment the values to produce animation.
  >
  > To avoid these kinds of problems, the recommended way to work with rotations is to avoid relying on consistent results when reading `.eulerAngles` particularly when attempting to gradually increment a rotation to produce animation. For better ways to achieve this, see the `Quaternion * operator`.

  so you should rather go for `Quaternion` and do e.g.
- And then you are using `transform.TransformDirection(Vector2.up)` which is a **direction** and pass it to your line renderer as a **position**.

  What you want there is rather the position combined from

  ```
  transform.position + transform.up
  ```

So together it should probably rather be

```
public LineRenderer lineRenderer;
public LayerMask layerMask;
public float laserSpeed;

private Quaternion originalRotation;
private Quaternion minRotation;
private Quaternion maxRotation;

void Start()
{
    originalRotation = transform.rotation;

    minRotation = originalRotation * Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, -90);
    maxRotation = originalRotation * Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 90);
}

void Update()
{
    // Note that Vector3 is a "struct" -> there is no need to manually use "new Vector3(transform.position.x, ...)"
    var startPosition = transform.position;

    lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, startPosition);
    
    var factor = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * laserSpeed, 1);

    // instead of the eulers rather use Quaternion
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(minRotation, maxRotation, factor);

    // "transform.up" basically equals using "transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.up)"
    var rayCast = Physics2D.Raycast(startPosition, transform.up, 10f, layerMask);

    if(rayCast.collider)
    {
        // when you hit something actually use this hit position as the end point for the line
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, rayCast.point);
    }
    else
    {
        // otherwise from the start position go 10 units in the up direction of your rotated object
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, startPosition + transform.up * 10f);
    }  
}
```

Comment: @stalwart1014 Don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359) this answer if it helped!